Postgresql query argument of IS TRUE must be type boolean, not type text
I have this Postgresql query:
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT b.message::json AS response,
    a.quote_reference AS quote_reference,
    b.message AS message_text
            FROM quote_table a
            JOIN messages_table b on a.quote_id = b.quote_id
                WHERE
                b.service = 'MYSQRVICE'
                AND b.call_type = 'RESPONSE'
                AND a.transaction_timestamp >= '2024-06-01'
    ORDER BY b.date_created desc
    )
SELECT
    CASE WHEN response -> 'detailed' -> 'full' ->> 'hibCodeUsed' is true
        THEN 'False'
    ELSE
        'True'
    END AS hibCodeUsed,
    quote_reference,
    message_text
FROM cte;

When I run it I get

ERROR:  argument of IS TRUE must be type boolean, not type text
LINE 16:  CASE WHEN response -> 'comprehensive' -> 'full' -...
^
SQL state: 42804
Character: 608

How do I perform this check?

@Dai That would cause argument of IS TRUE must be type boolean, not type json, no?

Well, what is in hibCodeUsed, and what is your desired outcome?

You can check different values.
Since it is not clear in your question what you want to check, I will assume 2 options.

Check value for key hibCodeUsed. There field values 'true' and 'false'. Compare field value with constant 'true'.
Check for existence of key hibCodeUsed. If key not exists in json, we get null - so, check is null.

See example with message(responce) '{"detailed":{"full":{"hibCodeUsed":true}}}'
create table quote_table(quote_id int, quote_reference json,transaction_timestamp timestamp);
insert into quote_table values
(1,'{"quote_reference":"reference1"}',current_timestamp);
select * from quote_table;

create table messages_table(id int,quote_id int,service varchar(30),call_type varchar(30)
     ,message json,date_created date);
insert into messages_table values
 (100,1,'MYSQRVICE','RESPONSE','{"detailed":{"full":{"hibCodeUsed":true}}}',current_date)
;

Some checks possible
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT b.message::json AS response,
    a.quote_reference AS quote_reference,
    b.message AS message_text
            FROM quote_table a
            JOIN messages_table b on a.quote_id = b.quote_id
                WHERE
                b.service = 'MYSQRVICE'
                AND b.call_type = 'RESPONSE'
                AND a.transaction_timestamp >= '2024-06-01'
    ORDER BY b.date_created desc
    )
SELECT
    CASE WHEN response -> 'detailed' -> 'full' ->> 'hibCodeUsed' ='true'
    -- CASE WHEN response -> 'detailed' -> 'full' -> 'hibCodeUsed' is not null
        THEN 'False'
    ELSE
        'True'
    END AS hibCodeUsed,
    quote_reference,
    message_text,
      -- check is true
    response -> 'detailed' -> 'full' ->> 'hibCodeUsed' ='true' as BoolResult,
      -- get value
    response -> 'detailed' -> 'full' ->> 'hibCodeUsed' get_hibCodeUsed,
        -- get value. not null
    response -> 'detailed' -> 'full' -> 'hibCodeUsed' exists_hibCodeUsed,
       -- get  value. null
    response -> 'detailed' -> 'full' -> 'Key_NoExist' Key_NotExist
FROM cte;

Output is



hibcodeused
quote_reference
message_text
boolresult
get_hibcodeused
exists_hibcodeused
key_notexist




False
{"quote_reference" :"reference1"}
{"detailed":{"full":{"hibCodeUsed":true}}}
t
true
true
null



Demo
